# Which escaping to use to insert a regular expression into database and getting it back unaltered?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

What is the best way to insert a regular expression into a database and read it, I tried some php functions like

- htmlentities()
- htmlspecialchars()
- serialize()

But after I fetch the regular expression from MySQL I can't use it, it doesn't work.
I tried with a text file to save the regular expression and result was same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if u want to insert some special character into mysql then `htmlentities()` is useful with **falgs**

```
ENT_COMPAT  Will convert double-quotes and leave single-quotes alone.
ENT_QUOTES  Will convert both double and single quotes.
ENT_NOQUOTES  Will leave both double and single quotes unconverted.
ENT_IGNORE  Silently discard invalid code 

htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

`htmlspecialchar()` only convert some special characters to HTML entities like

```
'&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
'"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
''' (single quote) becomes '&#039;' only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
'<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
'>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
```

also read

#### [html_entity_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-encode.php)

#### [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

### [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

### [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

***HAPPY TO HELP :)***

Comment: You misread the question. He was asking how to store some text containing special characters (in this case a regexp) in the database.

Comment: @konerak did u read first line `Whats the best way to insert regular expression into database?`

Comment: Yes. He wants to INSERT some text in the database. The text happens to be a regular expression. You just gave some existing MySQL commands to put in the where-clause which have to do with SELECT'ing stuff from a database, not INSERT'ing.

Comment: @user71... your Welcome :) please change the username..some good name